# How to return unique dates from a column, Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have date, name, and paid amount columns. I  want to return each unique date in a row and for each unique date return all the names and summed paid amounts.

```
=query(A:X,"SELECT V, SUM(X) WHERE A= date '2020-08-11' GROUP BY V")
```

this is what I have right now. This is returning the names and summed paid amounts for this date
but I there are many other dates and in this case I would have to manually edit the date.

```
V = names
X = paid amount
A = dates
```

Data Structure I am looking for

```
Date
2020-08-20                                          2020-08-21
Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-20  Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-21
Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-20  Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-21
Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-20  Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-21
Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-20  Courier Name Summed Paid Amount for the 2020-08-21
```

Link for what I have right now:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JR20wsd9bAsQLEtRpqbPNOoDionA6sOmCVUibGPrOKA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If you make the link Editable, rather than View Only, I can test/demo some solutions on a different tab for you

Comment: One second, I am trying to do it right now.

Comment: You should be able to edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pivot query I added to the sheet. I think this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```
=query(A1:C19,"SELECT B, SUM(C) WHERE A is not null GROUP BY B PIVOT A label SUM(C)''")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will leave the sheet open for other people with the same issue.